# Bound column to a list and loop...Is it possible at all?

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, telerik-grid

I'm  a novice Telerik Grid user and was wondering if it is a possibility to use Telerik Grid such that I bound one column to a string array and then somehow loop through it to show the array items as list.

StoreViewModel:(One store can have multiple displays)

`public string Name { get; set; }`

```
public string[] StoreDisplays { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
private IQueryable<StoreViewModel> GetRetailers()
{
var stores = from sg in db.Store
select new RetailerViewModel
{ 
  Name = sg.sg_Name,
  Name = sg.sg_Name,
  StoreDisplays = (   from ca in db.Categories.Where(item => item.c_ParentId == null)
               join sd in db.StoreDisplays.Where(item => item.sd_StoreGroupId == sg.sg_Id)
```

on ca.c_Id equals sd.sd_CategoryId into gj

```
               from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select (ca.c_Name)).ToArray<string>()
};
return stores;
}
```

Index.aspx

```
<%= Html.Telerik().Grid<StoreLocatorBackOffice.Models.RetailerViewModel>(Model) <br/>
        .Name("Grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        { 
            columns.Bound(sg => sg.Name)
            columns.Bound(sg => sg.StoreDisplays);
        }) 
        .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding 
                .Ajax()
                    .Select("_Index", "Retailer", true)
        ) 
        .Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Enabled(false))
        .Sortable(sorting => sorting
            .OrderBy(sortOrder => sortOrder.Add(p => p.Name).Ascending())) 
        .Pageable(settings => settings.PageSize((int)ViewData["pageSize"])) 
        .Filterable(filtering => filtering.Enabled(true))
        .Footer(true)
        %>
```

Currently it Displays like this.

```
Name              Store Display
Store#1           Display#1Display#2Display#6
Store#2           Display#3Display#9
```

And want to some how show it as follows.

```
Name       Store Display
Store#1    Display#1
           Display#2
           Display#6

Store#2    Display#3
           Display#9
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
columns.Bound(sg => sg.StoreDisplays);
```

You should bind using a template. That template can be whatever you want, (even another grid).

Here's a template that will put an image in:

```
columns.Template(c => {
        %>
            <img 
                alt="<%= c.CustomerID %>" 
                src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Grid/Customers/" + c.CustomerID + ".jpg") %>" 
              />
        <%
        });
```

Changing that template to display a list should be simple. 
Look [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/templatesserverside) for more info.

Comment: How can I loop for(`public string[] StoreDisplays { get; set; }`) inside the template?

Answer (score 0):

I would use HTML tags in to make data to spread vertically

For example

```
StoreDisplays = "    
<ul>
    <li>Display#1</li>
    <li>Display#2</li>
    <li>Display#3</li>
</ul>";  


.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(o => o.StoreDisplays).ClientTemplate("<#= StoreDisplays #>");
}
```

Comment: No, it won't. Example usage: columns.Bound(o => o.StoreDisplays).ClientTemplate("<#= StoreDisplays #>");

Comment: But it only works when clienttemplate is fired...and clienttemplate is not fired when loaded initially. I actually solved it as follows.

columns.Bound(sg => sg.StoreDisplays).Template(sg => string.Join("<li/>", sg.StoreDisplays.Split(',').OrderBy(o=>o.ToString())))
    .ClientTemplate("<#= listStoreDisplays(StoreDisplays) #>").Sortable(false);

where listStoreDisplays is javascript function that loops on each string element and then add the ul and li tags.